# iPhone email setup

Tags: iphone

I have two email accounts, A and B. On a laptop, I have forwarding from B to A, and I am able to reply from both email addresses when I check A. I added both accounts to the iPhone as well. However, in order for me to be able to reply from both addresses, the iPhone regularly checks messages from both accounts, resulting in duplicates due to forwarding.

Is there a way to add B as a reply address to the iPhone without fetching mail from B?

Comment: Is the mail server POP/IMAP/[Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/can-i-set-the-sender-reply-to-address-in-ios-mail-for-an-activesync-account)/[iCloud](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110816/how-to-send-an-email-through-an-outlook-com-alias-email-address-on-ios)? For some there is limited hope to send from an alias - from others you'll need to jailbreak the iOS (if it's even possible in Mail.app) or use a different sending app. iOS 7 does now allow you to list several emails under IMAP account information - so it depends heavily on your provider.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I'd go directly in B's email forwarding settings and set all the forwarded emails to be conscripted to a certain behavior - i.e. delete the email message or archive the email message or place it under a certain folder once the message was forwarded to A.

It's the only way I could think of for your iPhone not to receive emails under inbox for email B.